Is the definition of inductive set in Discrete Mathematics the same as that in Set Theory?
James Heine in Discrete Mathematics (second edition), chapter 3, section 3.1, page 128 defines inductive set as "objects constructed, in some way, from objects that are already in the set."  James Heine context is applications to Computer Science.  He's thinking of sets such as: $0 \in S$ and $x \in S$ implies $x + 1 \in S$.
Now contrast that with books on Set Theory.  We get definitions such as Wolfram's and Wikipedia's.  Wolfram's begins by saying that it's a set-theoretic term having a number of different meanings.  He mentions that Fraenkel considers inductive set as synonym of finite set.  (Not what we're looking at from James Heine perspective.)  Wolfram's second definition comes from Bertrand Russell: a nonempty partially ordered set in which every element has a successor.  Russell's definition does seem to match James Heine, but I'm not sure.  Is James Heine definition the same as Bertrand Russell's?

It looks to me like Heine's heuristic definition is based on examples of structures like Russell's more precise definition is describing.

Heine's is more general than Russell's: successor is a special case of constructed from previous elements.  While I don't know the details of Fraenkel's, but I would guess the finitude is that of the single elements, not that of the set...

See Axiom of infinity
